# Using google apis libraries- key required?

Tags: google-api, google-ajax-api, google-ajax-libraries

I'm confused about the proper use of google apis libraries.  Specifically, is a key required when using Google AJAX Libraries?

This OK?:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Or is this required:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key={myKey}"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key is not required to use the Google CDN. The first script tag above should be all you need.

Comment: I have used an API key in the past for the Google maps API, but it appears here http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#Introduction that you'll need one to use the google.load method in your script.  Hope that helps.